# Scala. Empty variable after Mapping

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm new in Scala and obviously don't understand why this code doesn't work.

I create array from first DataFrame, and when creating second array start checking for identical data in both arrays.
In case of identical data - implement variable **text**.

```
var text = "Hello!"
val dfOriginDate = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name, age FROM table2")
val arrOriginDate = dfOriginDate.rdd.map(r => {
     r(0).toString + r(1).toString
   }).collect()

val dfNewDate = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name, age FROM table")
dfNewDate.rdd.map(r => {
  if (arrOriginDate contains(r(0).toString + r(1).toString)) {
    text += "found some stupid things"
    print(text + " for the first time\r\n")
  }
}).collect()

println(text + " for the second time")
```

On output I have this:

```
Hello! found some stupid things for the first time
Hello! for the second time
```

Why when I'm printing **text** while mapping the variable is implementing, but when I'm printing it again after Map - seems like it never was in Map?

__

And when I'm trying do this with `ListBuffer[String]()` it gave me same effect.

What I'm trying to do with this code - find identical data in different tables from Cassandra
__
Don't know what answer is better ><  both is acceptable to my problem =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you write rdd.map does HUGE things on the backend. The reason you are seeing this behaviour is because your main code and the rdd.map function work in different threads. Variables cannot pass through and back simply in case of a parallel context.

Try using a an [accumulator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators) for this. This is why it is never recommended to use mutable variables. It confuses you in places where you shouldn't have been stuck had they been immutable.

Comment: Thank you! I think i need read some book about Scala\Spark combinations =)

Comment: As a method of learning try using a class that is not serializable (unlike String which is). You will get an object not serializable exception. What happens during the code run is as follows: You refer to a variable from the local context in parallel context. The variable gets serialized and gets passed on (through network if the task is running on a different machines) to the mapper.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about Scala, it's a Spark problem specifically. You can't use mutable variables like this, because code in the anonymous functions passed to `map` is going to be executed on other machines (that's the point of using Spark!) and will change *their* copy of `text`, not the one in the driver.

It's explained in detail http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka with a very similar example.

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't capture all picture in my mind